# If SOAP is now considered overengineered over REST why isn't WCF?

Tags: c#, java, web-services

I'm amazed that years over years IT pretend to simplify communication or software design and a few years later it declare it was over-engineered. EJB, SOAP, so looking at all the WCF stuffs do we as users (not as Microsoft or IBM who need to sell new stuffs) really need it ?

Update: this is a concrete example
http://www.go4answers.com/Example/expert-interoperability-issues-ws-736.aspx
The guy knows how to call a server with WS-Security using old soap and in WCF it seems it doesn't really help and worst it seems even more complicated as it is said:

"WCF has still some limitation - not all WS-Security configuration  are possible without custom development."

Nobody seems to be able to have found a solution.

So can people instead of mere opinions give **concrete examples** (with source code both in wcf and in soap or rest for comparison) of hard problems (and not easy problems) that can be solved by WCF more easily than can be with traditional soap ?

Comment: Everything is over-engineered something else. We don't need anything except assembly. Which is over-engineered 0's and 1's.

Comment: @Ryan: `0` and `1` were _grossly_ over-engineered from the start. All you really need is `0.5`.

Comment: I'm not sure where you get the idea that any of those things are "over engineered".  It's probably just someones opinion, and you know what they are like.  Everyone has one.

Comment: You're right I'm not interested by opinions I'd like to have concrete examples (with source code) of hard problems (and not easy problems) that can be solved by WCF more easily than can be with traditional soap ...

Answer (score 2):

What I like about WCF is that it can be as simple or as complex as you want it to be. I also really appreciate the separation between contract and binding, where you can clearly define your operations and have the option of choosing which transport to use.

Answer (score 2):

WCF is meant to make a developer's life easier. You can re-write the logic for a service, auto-wire multiple endpoints, and *voila*...your logic is available via SOAP, REST, Named Pipes, etc.

Unfortunately it's not as easy as it was all made to sound. Personally, though, I still find it a useful tool for re-using my code.

If you really want to jump on the bandwagon and say that REST/JSON is the only way to go...then WCF will definitely seem over-engineered. ASP.NET MVC does a great job at RESTful JSON services if you don't want to deal with the WCF overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of MVC JSON, that seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

With 4.0, they've simplified configuration. I find it very easy to do this. But realize WCF is designed to make a lot of the internals of communication between services transparent. You don't care if its SOAP, REST, etc. All you do is write your service and "hook them up". COde for my services is exactly like I'd write normal code, with the exception of a couple of attributes added to the class and methods and some configuration (with 4.0, very simple imho)

Comment: "Transparency" has a cost: you don't know how it really works so that when you have to solve a hard problem you're stuck see example http://www.go4answers.com/Example/expert-interoperability-issues-ws-736.aspx :)

Comment: True. I agree w you to a degree. But in many cases when I use WCF I don't care about the internals. I just need it to work, and 99.9% of the time, it works. You provide great points though...